# What happens if I dont include VSTOEE.dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I found a reference in microsoft visual studio for VSTOEE.dll, I googled it and landed here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx . I removed it from my project and my project still complies and nothing broke. I am not sure about its use and I don't want to just "leave it in" if its useless.

From my understanding, it is more of a nice to have (to make sure user has right tools) over must to have. Is it a bad practice to remove it?

Comment: Pretty hard to guess how you found this in a project, it is a required file and part of the VSTO runtime install.  It is not used to compile your project.  Do not remove it if this is a setup project.

Comment: Does that mean it isnt located in the right place? Can you shed a bit more light on it? About the file. Does it affect excel plug in or does it affect my visual studio? Why dont all my projects have that? I am just curious about it

Comment: Yeah, if you have an office project, it will use that DLL at runtime. But I don't think it is needed in the project itself. VS should create a reference to C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll when first creating a VSTO project. Version-depending, perhaps.